# Calculating a percentage column from a column where the values are derived from the count function

Tags: r, percentage, dplyr

I'm trying to create a percent column.

It works perfectly with my_data1 below but not my_data3 (the only difference between the two is that the value column in my_data3 is an integer. The problem persists however, even if I change the variable to a numeric).

**This works:**

```
my_data1 <- data.frame(Colour = c("Blue", "Red", "Green"),
                 Value = c(2, 3, 1))

my_data1 %>% 
  mutate(Percentage = Value/sum(Value)*100)



  Colour Value Percentage
1   Blue     2   33.33333
2    Red     3   50.00000
3  Green     1   16.66667
```

**But this doesn't work:**

```
my_data3 <- data.frame(Colour = c("Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red"))

my_data3 <- my_data3 %>% 
  group_by(Colour) %>% 
  count(name = "Value") 

my_data3 %>% 
  mutate(Percent = Value/sum(Value)*100)


  Colour Value Percent
  <fct>  <int>   <dbl>
1 Red        3     100
2 Blue       2     100
3 Green      1     100
```

*Any help / advice / explanation would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: The difference is that `data3` is grouped and since there's only one entry per group you're getting 100%

Comment: So this would work : `my_data3 %>% ungroup %>%
  mutate(Percent = Value/sum(Value)*100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the whole column as it is grouped with `.$`

```
my_data3 %>% 
   mutate(Percent = Value/sum(.$Value)*100)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Colour [3]
#  Colour Value Percent
#  <fct>  <int>   <dbl>
#1 Blue       2    33.3
#2 Green      1    16.7
#3 Red        3    50
```